# Filter Problem... multiple Filters and reset of filtered list in kotlin android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, filter

i have here a problem with the filtering... if i put in all filters and give the list to the adapter, and then change the filters... the filtered list gets used i guess... its not working anymore after a few times filtering... what can i do about it? i am not so long into programming please help me :)

```
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item: MenuItem? ->
        when (item?.itemId) {
            R.id.option1 -> {
                binding.ddbtSearch.text = "Matches"
                binding.ddbtLvl.visibility = View.VISIBLE // Show ddbtLvl
                viewModel.contacts.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                    var filteredList = it

                    filteredList = when (binding.ddbtLvl.text) {
                        "BEGINNER" -> filteredList.filter { it.level == "BEGINNER" }.toMutableList()
                        "IMPROVER" -> filteredList.filter { it.level == "IMPROVER" }.toMutableList()
                        "ADVANCED" -> filteredList.filter { it.level == "ADVANCED" }.toMutableList()
                        "PRACTITIONER" -> filteredList.filter { it.level == "PRACTITIONER" }.toMutableList()
                        "EXPERT" -> filteredList.filter { it.level == "EXPERT" }.toMutableList()
                        else -> filteredList
                    }

                    filteredList = when (binding.ddBtSports.text) {
                        "BADMINTON" -> filteredList.filter { it.sportsOne == "BADMINTON" }.toMutableList()
                        "SQUASH" -> filteredList.filter { it.sportsOne == "SQUASH" }.toMutableList()
                        "TISCHTENNIS" -> filteredList.filter { it.sportsOne == "TISCHTENNIS" }.toMutableList()
                        "TENNIS" -> filteredList.filter { it.sportsOne == "TENNIS" }.toMutableList()
                        "FUSSBALL" -> filteredList.filter { it.sportsOne == "FUSSBALL" }.toMutableList()
                        "HOCKEY" -> filteredList.filter { it.sportsOne == "HOCKEY" }.toMutableList()
                        "CRICKET" -> filteredList.filter { it.sportsOne == "CRICKET" }.toMutableList()
                        "HANDBALL" -> filteredList.filter { it.sportsOne == "HANDBALL" }.toMutableList()
                        else -> filteredList
                    }

                    filteredList = when (binding.ddBtSort.text) {
                        "ENTFERNUNG" -> filteredList.sortedBy { it.entfernung }.toMutableList()
                        "DATUM" -> filteredList.sortedBy { it.date }.toMutableList()
                        "WINS" -> filteredList.sortedBy { it.wins > myWins }.toMutableList()
                        "ALTER" -> filteredList.sortedBy { it.age > myAge }.toMutableList()
                        else -> filteredList
                    }

                    binding.btSearch.setOnClickListener {
                        binding.rvFinderResults.adapter = FinderResultAdapter(filteredList, viewModel)
                    }
                }
                true
            }
            R.id.option2 -> {
                binding.ddbtSearch.text = "Clubs"
                binding.ddbtLvl.visibility = View.GONE // Hide ddbtLvl
                viewModel.clubdatabase.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                    binding.rvFinderResults.adapter = ClubAdapter(it, viewModel)
                }
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }

    popupMenu.show()
}
```

i tryed multiple things, adding booleans, changing to sortyBy, trying to reset the list, but nothing really worked

Comment: Move this logic to the viewmodel, and dont use String in the level, sportsOne and entfernung, etc. try to use Enums.  Then in the filter you can add more logic: if (it.sportsOne == ReceivedSportsEnum && it.level == ReceivedLevelEnum).sortBy{}.  Maybe you can improve the results using hashmap or even the search algorithm Trie

Comment: Yes, thank you! didn't thought about Enum Classes... it workes!